# ¿What mistakes can be made when differentiating power series (e.g $\sin x$ power series)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$, but I don't know what is wrong with the following: $$\sin x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.$$ Now if I want to find its derivative, not term by term, but inside the $\sum$ sign, something that I can't seem to get my head around happens: $$\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sin x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots=\cos x-1$$

The 1 doesn't appear in the sum as it should. I know that if I start the sum of the derivative in $n=0$ I obviously get the result desired, but why should I? Usually if $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-a)^n$ then its derivative is $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nn(x-a)^{n-1}$ right?

I'll be deeply grateful if anybody can point out where am I missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Usually if $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-a)^n$ then its derivative is $f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nn(x-a)^{n-1}$ right?

Yes, because the $n=0$ term is just the constant $c_0$, and the derivative of a constant is zero so you can just forget it when you differentiate. But in the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$, the $n=0$ term is $x$, which isn't a constant. Its derivative is not zero, so you cannot forget it. There's no rule that says that every time you differentiate, you need to forget the $n=0$ term... Don't blindly apply rules without understanding them.

Your theorem says that if you have a series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (x-a)^n$, then its derivative is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n n (x-a)^{n-1}$. In the theorem, the exponent of $(x-a)$ for the $n$th term is $n$; this is not the case in the power series for $\sin$, where it is $2n+1$. So if you really want to apply your theorem as is, you need to make a small modification: let
$$c_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} & n = 2k + 1 \\
0 & n \text{ is even}
\end{cases}$$
So for example $c_0 = 0$, $c_1 = 1$, $c_2 = 0$, $c_3 = -1/3!$... And then $\sin x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$. Thus you can apply your theorem and get as derivative $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n n x^{n-1}$. So you get $1 - x^2/2 + \dots$ as expected.

Comment: Thank you, I know all of that, but I'm not applying a "blind" rule, it's a theorem, so the question is what part of the theorem I'm not applying properly. Doing it term by term you notice that you can't just "forget" about the the term $x$ and I know that by not doing I get what I want, but the thing is that the theorem states the following:

Comment: If $\sum c_n(x-a)^n$ has a radius of convergence $R>0$, let us define a function $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-a)^n, |x-a|<R.$$ This function has derivatives of every order needed inside the interval, therefore it is possible to obtain the derivatives term by term: $$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(x-a)^{n-1}, \ f'(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)c_n(x-a)^{n-2},$$ and like that successively. Each one of the derived series converge in every interior point in the interval $a-R<x<a+R$

Comment: See my edited answer @Eesu.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the term for $n=0$ for the expansion of $\sin x$, as it is a function of $x$, i.e. evaluates to $x$, so your derivative will be $1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your powers are of the form $x^{2n+1}$, so for $n=0$ this has some nonzero coefficient $c_1$. Usually, we drop the $n=0$ term since it's derivative is zero, but this is not the case here!